# Simple query taking long (~15 seconds)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, time

I have the following query and php-code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT j.OrderID, DATE_FORMAT(j.StartDate,'%W %e %M %Y %H:%i:%s') AS StartDate, 
                        j.Object, j.Signature,  j.PrintedWithBSN, j.PrintedWithoutBSN,
                        p.ProjectID AS ProjectName, p.City, p.PostalCode, p.StreetName, 
                        c.Name AS CustomerName
        FROM JobOrder j
        INNER JOIN Project p ON p.ProjectID = j.ProjectID
        INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN OrderEmployer oe ON j.OrderID=oe.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Employer e ON oe.EmployerID=e.EmployerID
        WHERE j.Removed = 0 AND Date(j.StartDate)=:StartDate
        ORDER BY e.Firstname, p.WorkDone, j.Signature, j.StartDate DESC, c.Name";

$query = $database->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array('StartDate' => $date));";
```

Using the microtime php-function, I found out the `$query->execute` takes about 15 seconds to complete. One year ago, the query was executed in just seconds. I cannot figure out what is causing the extra waiting time, is it my bad query writing?

-------Edit:
My EXPLAIN result:

[image: Explain Plan results]

-------Edit2:
My indexes are (per table):

- Customer: **Primary Key:** CustomerID                 **Unique Key:** Name
- Employer: **Primary key:** EmployerID                 **Unique Key:** Username
- JobOrder: **Primary Key:** OrderID                    **Key:** ProjectID
- OrderEmployer: **Primary Key:** OrderID, EmployerID   **Key:** EmployerID
- Project **Primary Key:** ProjectID **Key:** CustomerID, ContactPersonID, ContactPersonProjectID

Comment: Could it be the volume of data you are now processing? Check the columns that ARE indexed and those that may help the query that ARE NOT indexed

Comment: You could show us the output from an EXPLAIN on this query

Comment: Please share indexing details on the tables in your query

Comment: What indexes do you have? You should have one on j.StartDate; but you'd still need to change the `DATE(j.StartDate)=` condition as function calls on fields eliminate the possibility of using indexes. You'd need something like  `j.StartDate >= :StartDate AND j.StartDate < :StartDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: This is what flies as a "simple" query nowadays?

Comment: *One year ago, the query was executed in just seconds* ... is this based off memory? Couldn't 15 seconds be *just seconds*?

Comment: @Parfait, This query is executed on a system for a few years. The system (database) is filled with new data every day. So about one year ago, the query was still fast and I cannot recall long waiting times, until the last few months...

Comment: `WHERE j.Removed = 0 AND Date(j.StartDate)=:StartDate` doesn't use an index. If the `JobOrder` table has grown very large, this will slow it down.

Comment: @Uueerdo and Barmar, I will check your recommendations tomorrow when I have access to a pc. Can someone explain to me why the j.Startdate needs to use an index to improve the speed?

Comment: Without an index on a field used in a condition, MySQL must inspect every row of a table to find all matching rows (or every row from a set narrowed by a another index used in the query). With an index, MySQL can identify the rows much faster; you can kind of think of the rows as partially pre-sorted on the index; or kind of like looking at the index at the end of a book instead of scanning each page for a term. _...and I said the condition would need changed because MySQL would be indexing j.StartDate not the result of somefunc(j.StartDate)_

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Uueerdo. This makes sense, I will try it out asap and will post the results back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the tips of Uueerdo and Barmar I have fixed the long query time. By simply adding an index to the fields that are used by the WHERE clause, I have reduced the query time to less than 0,1s (I have even seen 0,00019192695617676 seconds)!

Comment: 0.2ms sounds like the Query cache kicked in.  Rerun it with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Comment: Hi @RickJames, with SQL_NO_CACHE it still gives rather fast results:
0.0609 seconds for example. But the 0,00019192695617676 seconds result is indeed probably due to caching.

Comment: 61ms sounds realistic.  And you see that an index _may_ speed up a query by 300x.  My cookbook on building indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql